# What is the best machine Learning model to train time series data? [ Not forecasting ]

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a set of time series data belong to 5 different classes. [ EEG data (1 data point for 1 second). And those data have been divided in to 30-40 second epochs and each epoch is classified into different classes like A,B,C,D,E]. So basically I have around 13500 labelled data.

```
[10,5,48,75,1,...,22,45,8] = A
[26,47,8,77,4,...,56,88,96] = B  like wise
```

What I did was I directly fed these data to a Neural Network and trained the model. But the accuracy was very low around 40%. What want to know is rather than just using a neural network, what is the best model to train time series data?

Answer (score 1):

In case of time series data some architectures are performing quite well :

- **Recurrent Neural Network** (with LSTM, GRU or BERT for example), designed to train on sequence of data

This could be an example : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.04818.pdf

How this works inside : [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/illustrated-guide-to-lstms-and-gru-s-a-step-by-step-explanation-44e9eb85bf21)

Example implementation in keras : [link](https://stackabuse.com/time-series-analysis-with-lstm-using-pythons-keras-library/)
, you should then find/design your own architecture

- **TCN**, it uses causal and dilated convolution in order to capture time series data

Example : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.03806.pdf

How this works : [link](https://medium.com/@raushan2807/temporal-convolutional-networks-bfea16e6d7d2)

Implementation in keras : [link](https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-tcn)

I would personnaly go for those types of architecture, well suited for time series data.